# How to allow cross site origin requests in Google App Engine?

Tags: express, google-app-engine, cors, app-engine-flexible

I have a simple API made with Express that is returning json. The Express server is running on Google App Engine. I'm using cors (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to enable ALL CORS-requests, but I still get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." when doing AJAX requests from a SPA application.

`app.use(cors())`

Default settings for above according to the documentation is: 

`{ "origin": "*", 
"methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE", 
"preflightContinue": false, 
"optionsSuccessStatus": 204 
}`

That should be enough since I'm only doing a simple GET-request from my SPA.

Any ideas?

Comment: Go ahead and add some code you have tried.

Comment: @JoeyPhillips Changed the question a bit with some more info

Answer (score 2):

App Engine supports CORS through the *app.yaml* file as mentioned here: [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element)

Inside your *app.yaml* file, modify the `handlers` section by adding `http_headers` element like the following:

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
  # ...
```

Afterwards, you can redeploy your App Engine to apply the configuration changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As I understand it, that is for static files. In my case, where I have a simple API doing json-responses, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header should be set inside the code (i.e. by using the cors module or something else). And this does not work for me.

Comment: Any idea what the required fields are for this? I tried just adding the http_headers but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really confused by the doc, because it implies that CORS headers can only be sent when serving static content, not the more common scenario where CORS tells the browser it's OK to accept JSON or XML from the backend when called via a third-party hosted script.

My workaround is to just return it as a custom header within the app itself.  For example, with Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def root():
     import traceback
     try:
         data = {'key1': "value1", 'key2': "value2"}
         return jsonify(data), 200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"}
     except:
         return format(traceback.format_exc()), 500,  {'Content-Type': "text/plain"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Both official solutions did nothing for me — both the app.yaml `http_headers` property and using python `CORS(app)`. That cors, *always* an hour of hair pulling, every time it pops up.

Answer (score -1):

As I answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62075272/2235936

Don't need those `handlers` stuff in app.yaml, just set CORS on the G storage bucket.

Comment: The question is about Google App Engine, not Cloud Storage !